# Styling Buttons with HTML

Tags: html

Pretty basic question regarding button styling in HTML. I'm essentially just trying to link these buttons out and change the color and potentially the size.  I realize I have to do this within HTML and no CSS

Here is what I have so far:

```html
 <span style="color: blue;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Listen for Free:
    <a class="button" font color="black" href="#">Spotify</a>
    <a class="button">Soundcloud</a>
    <a class="button">YouTube</a>
    </span>
```

I've been doing some investigation and here is what I know so far:

1. I will have to use the `<a>` property since I'm within HTML
2. Would `<span>` be used properly here?
3. The font color="black" is not showing any results

Comment: Are you saying you *can't* use CSS? Or are you asking what the inline style should be...? You changed the font-color of the `span` properly, why are you suddenly trying `font color="black"` on the links?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Also, `font color="black"` is invalid and you're missing a closing span tag.

Comment: `font color="black"` should be `style="color:black;`

But you should start to read again the basics of html/css

Answer (score 1):

- Use CSS for styling (avoid inline styling whenever you can)
- Close everything you open

```css
.blue {color: blue;}
.ulined {text-decoration: underline;}
.blk {color: black;}
```

```html
<span class="blue"><span class="ulined">Listen for Free:</span>
    <a class="button blk" href="#">Spotify</a>
    <a class="button">Soundcloud</a>
    <a class="button">YouTube</a>
    </span>
```

Answers to your 3 sub-questions:

1. Anchors are used for linking, using a `href` attribute (like your 1st button)
2. `span` is not the ideal element to wrap all the anchors, `div` sounds like a better choice semantically. Like this:

```css
.blue {color: blue;}
.ulined {text-decoration: underline;}
.blk {color: black;}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
  <span class="ulined">Listen for Free:</span>
  <a class="button blk" href="#">Spotify</a>
  <a class="button">Soundcloud</a>
  <a class="button">YouTube</a>
</div>
```

3. Attributes can't have spaces, you probably wanted inline `style`, but it's better to use a CSS class instead

Seems like you needs to learn quite a lot about HTML and CSS. 
Here's a good starting point: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web